# Body Content Will Not Center Vertically

Tags: html, css, centering

I've created a simple webpage (please ignore the php). I would like to have all the content in the body centered - it's aligned horizontally (via  text-align:center), But I can't get it to align vertically on the top and bottom.

Link to JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6q1a1b01/1/

I've tried:

```
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
vertical-align: middle;
```

I would appreciate any insight as to why the content is not being centered vertically despite these two attempts.

HTML:

```
<body>
<h1>Welcome to my website!</h1>
<h2>Please login below.</h2>
<h3>Don't have an account? Create one here.</h3>

<div class="formFormat" >  
<div  id="table1">
<form name="loginForm" method="post" action="<?php? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];>" >
  <table id="cssTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" id="user" name="user" value="<?php echo $user_name?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td><td><input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" value="<?php echo $user_password?>"/></td>
    </tr>
      </table>
  </form>
  </div>

  <div id="table2">
  <form>
  <table> 
  <tr>
     <td><input type="submit" name="submitLogin"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td id="createAccount">Create an account.</td>
   </tr>

  </table>
</form>
  </form>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-color: white;
   background-image: url(https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1429091967365-492aaa5accfe);
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.formFormat{    
  padding: 10px;
  height: auto;
  width:auto;
  border: 1px black solid;
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;

}

#table1 {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

#table2 {
  display:inline-block;

}

#createAccount {
  font-style: italic;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

input[type="text"] {
    border : 1px solid ;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    border : 1px solid ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/6q1a1b01/3/.

**Include this code just below `<body>`**

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">
```

**Include this code just above `</body>`**

```
</div>
</div>
```

**Include this code in your CSS:**

```
.outer {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vertically aligning to middle of the screen won't be possible using `vertical-align: middle;` property.

Few ways you could do:

1. Use FlexBox layout
2. Use CSS Table
3. Fixed Height and Position Trick, see here - http://jsfiddle.net/mho8ytv7/

Few suggestions for your HTML based on your JSFiddle codes:

- You can't have FORM elements nested.
- User One Heading for this simpler page and others use css to style.

Source: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Look at this and see if that could help you : 
[vertical align anything with just 3 lines of css](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)